# Refactor code to avoid ciruclar dependencing when import modules with Ecmascript 6 and webpack

Tags: javascript, webpack, ecmascript-6, refactoring

With the objective to simplify my life in maintaining code, I started to refactor it in multiple modules, and make use of webpack.

I would like to keep each file for an area, as example, utility, graphics UI functions, configuration, and so on, and keep them small.

I am doubtful about how to refactor some modules which both make use of other libraries.

Say, for example, I want to use a graph layout library - I will pick Vivagraph.js - and look at this simple example here:

https://github.com/anvaka/VivaGraphJS/blob/master/demos/tutorial_svg/02%20-%20Create%20Custom%20Node.html

where here defines the "graphic engine":

```
var graphics = Viva.Graph.View.svgGraphics();
```

and then the rendering :

```
var renderer = Viva.Graph.View.renderer(graph, {
                    graphics : graphics
                });
```

In my application, I extended the graphic and UX part.
As example, with functions associated to nodes interaction, and with functions associated to the look and feel.

I might do something like this, to keep separate the graphic engine on one file, and keep the graph object and rendering on another file (e.g. the main application):

```
// customUI.js
import Viva from 'vivagraphjs'
import ux from 'customUX.js

var graphics = Viva.Graph.View.svgGraphics();


graphics.node(function(node) {
                // create the UI object for the node

                customUX( ui ).function( event) { // associate interaction to the node })

            })

// other instruction to make the graph rendering look nice 

export {graphics};
```

and

```
//main app.js

import Viva from 'vivagraphjs'
import {graphics} from 'customUI.js'

var graph = Viva.Graph.graph(); 

var renderer = Viva.Graph.View.renderer(graph, {
                    graphics : graphics
                });
```

I am afraid to double import the main library (Vivagraph in this case) and make circular dependencies, so instead of simplifying the code I create a messy build.

Can you advice on best pattern to refactor the code ?

Please note I don't aim to become a master of webpack. I mean I am considering also learning curve and time to pick up new tools to refactor the code VS constant little improvement on the library I built. If possible I would like to avoid disassemble or import modules of used libraries here and there - like import the graphic enginge from a library in one file, and the rendering in another file.

Tips to keep things organized and clean, but not to complicated on the management, are appreciated.

Comment: A module being imported multiple times does not mean you have circular dependencies. I can't see the problem.

Comment: Oh, then I misunderstood: see the example before. library *V* is imported by file *a*, *b*. File *a* imports file *b*. So I thought that in final bundle *V* may be imported twice. Does a circular import only happen if *b* also import *a* ?

Comment: Looking in the example above, in *app.js* I may create a `graph` object. How could I pass that graph object within  `graphics` object or other functions in the file *customUI.js* ? Shall I do `import graph from app.js`in customUI.js?

Comment: Yes, it's circular if *a* depends on *b* and *b* depends on *a*. This would indeed happen if you did `import { graph } from 'app.js';` in *customUI.js*. You better avoid that. Instead, just pass `graph` as a parameter to functions imported from the other module similar to how you pass it to `Viva.Graph.View.renderer`. Or alternatively, just move the `const graph = …` line into *customUI.js*, and import the `graph` from there alongside with the `graphics` into *main*.